# bizarre behavior from Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am having extremely odd behavior from numpy, I have an object containing a numpy array but for some reason I cannot set its value to decimal numbers.

I never explicitly gave the array a type, I thought numpy did automatic type casting to floats?

[image]

Comment: Well, can you `print(self.angles.dtype)`? The type is obviously not floating point. Does the array perhaps come from a pandas series, which already has an associated type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

> If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type
> required to hold the objects in the sequence.

In this case, the dtype is `int32`, which represent integers.

If you look at the actual signature of `numpy.array`, the default value for `dtype` is `None` implying that there is more to it than just choosing `float64`.

You should also recall that you can declare an array of strings. If the actual default type was `float64`, then you'd expect an exception unless you declared the type for the strings.

It is good practice to declare your `dtype`. Because

```
x = np.array([1.0, 2, 3])
```

will be given a `dtype` of `float64`, but down the road, if you change the `1.0` to just `1`, suddenly it becomes `int32`. If you wrote other code that assumes `x` stores floats, bugs will immediately appear.

Even worse, is that if you want to store some moderately large numbers (but not ones that are all that uncommon):

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
x[1] = 5e9
# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

This raises an exception at runtime because `5e9` exceeds the maximum value that can be stored as an int32, whereas if you had written

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype="int64")
x[1] = 5e9
# Perfectly legal
```

you would not encounter this exception for this particular assignment.

Comment: Thanks, I never use to care about types but lesson learned!

Comment: @FourierFlux Glad I could help